# Pytest is not detecting tests when the test class extends Base class

Tags: python, pytest

tests are not detected by pytest when test class extends Base class.
result is same when triggering tests with pycharm or from command line.

what changes should be done so that pytest detects tests in an extended class?

Below error is shown and displays the message "Empty Suite"

python: 3.8.14

pytest: 7.2.0

ERROR: not found: /Users/a/Documents/new/src/test/hsse/test_a.py::Test::test_a
(no name '/Users/a/Documents/new/src/test/hsse/test_a.py::Test::test_a' in any of [])

file: src/main/base/base.py

```
class Base():
    def some(self):
        return "a"
```

file: src/test/dira/test_a.py

```
class Test_A(Base):
    def test_a(self):
        assert something
```

If i do not extend Test_A from Base, then pytest is detecting tests and running them.
i tried searching online and few posts. but didn't find any such problem.

Comment: Help us help you - share a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is not reproducible: why would you derive a test class from a production code class, as you seem to be doing?

Comment: I am only extending Test_A class from a Base class. Intention being Base class would have some common code that many test classes can utilize.